# how to convert string to float in python?

Tags: python

I wrote a function that inputs a string expression and i want to split the expression and use some of the content as float. i tried writing `num1 = float(temp[0])`
but i got an error message saying i cant convert string to float.
How can i do that in python?
Here is the part of my code:

```
def calculate_from_string(expression):
    temp = expression.split(" ")
    num1 = float(int(temp[0]))
    num2 = float(int(temp[1]))
    oop = temp[2]
    return calculate_mathematical_expression(num1, num2, oop)
```

The type of expression is string.
i tried converting it this way but it didn't work on the tester i was using because i got a message that it is an invalid expression. Does anyone know how i can do it?

Comment: `float(int(a))` is unfortunately totally incorrect as it loses all the precision. For example, `float(int("3.1415926"))` will result in an error.

Comment: how is your expression will be ?

Comment: and what was the error message you got?

Comment: At the least, you should show us what the input which fails looks like. Defining what sort of expressions you actually want to be able to parse wouldn't hurt either. `(1 + 7) * ((2 << 3) - 1)` is a perfectly valid exprepression, yet that's definitely not something such a simplistic parser can ever cope with.

Comment: What value is your `expression ` variable holding?

Comment: You can convert a string to a float. `float("1.23")` works fine. `float("x")` will produce the error you're seeing. What value were you passing in?

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you provided a snippet of your data to us. 
I don't know what you were doing but this should work (and it does for me):

```
str_expression = '1 57 34'
num = [float(i) for i in str_expression.split()]
```

you could also use a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.array(str_expression.split(), dtype=np.float)
```

If your expression contains some alphanumerics, you can just use regular expressions to extract the numbers.
For example:

```
str_expression = 'bdjsbd bdka2 23 (34 >> 4) * 2ds'
```

the right way to extract the numbers would be:

```
import re

nums = [float(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', str_expression)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def calculate_from_string(expression):
    temp = expression.split(" ")
    num1 = float(temp[0])
    num2 = float(temp[1])
    oop = temp[2]
    return calculate_mathematical_expression(num1, num2, oop)
```

`float( int( "123.45" ) )` will raise ValueError since int expect `[0-9]+` but you have `.` in the string, which will raise value error.

2nd point if you will call `int(4.5)` then it will give you 4, so be careful when using int function.

But you can use float(int(string)) if your input string doesn't contain `.` e.g. `float(int("1234"))` which will give you `1234.0`

Comment: user is already having `float(int(temp[0]))` in his code snippet. You do not know the value `expression` is holding. There might be any reason for this behavior

Comment: As mentioned at last temp[0] may be having `.` , which is causing failure.